# Xcode 7.5 beta-No Known instance method for selector 'accessibilityValue'

Tags: objective-c, apple-watch, xcode7-beta5

I have open my application for Xcode 7.5 beta, I am getting following error in Apple Watch code - [image] Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't use images for showing textual information. Copy the code, highlight it with *Ctrl+K* and comment (if necessary), whenever it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your line to

```
NSString *eventId = [(ArtistRow*)theRow accessibilityValue];
```

Otherwise, even though you have checked that your row controller is of class `ArtistRow` compiler still treats it as `id` (which is the return type from `rowControllerAtIndex:`)

Comment: Hi Andriy , I din't declared any variable of name 'accessibilityValue' in my 'ArtistRow' class . So if i am typecasting it doesn't affect it.

Comment: @user3185320 if ArtistRow and its superclasses don't have a variable 'accessibilityValue' then why are you finding it strange that compiler throws an error? :)

Comment: apple already provided these properties like 'tag' , 'accessibilityValue', 'accessibilityLabel'  I am using that property to setting it's value like - '[theRow setAccessibilityValue:eventDataObj.EventID];' which is f9 , but getting issue while accessing this value in Xcode 7.5 beta

Comment: @user3185320 this is a very strange issue. I am testing identical code in Xcode 7 beta 5 and it is working fine. Is there any chance that you can share your actual source code? Or maybe you can create a dummy app which reproduces this issue? It would really help